# Getting Average Count Between Datetime From/To Specific Hours

Tags: mysql

I would like to make a statistic for the record on my database where I want to calculate the average number when the user login to the system from/to certain datetime and in each 4 hours per day

simple example: I want to get the average of successful login from '2016-09-20 00:00:00' to '2016-09-23 23:59:59' where the result should be given on these certain times ('00:00:00' - '11:59:59') and ('12:00:00' - '23:59:59')

This is a list of an example data (where status 1 means success, 0 meant not):

```
| id | | driver_id |    login_timedate     | status |
|  1 | |    1    | '2016-09-20 00:00:11' |    1   |
|  2 | |    2    | '2016-09-20 01:16:09' |    1   |
|  3 | |    2    | '2016-09-20 23:01:16' |    1   |
|  4 | |    3    | '2016-09-21 04:04:59' |    1   |
|  5 | |    3    | '2016-09-21 05:06:59' |    0   |
|  6 | |    2    | '2016-09-21 16:06:59' |    1   |
|  7 | |    1    | '2016-09-22 00:16:59' |    1   |
|  8 | |    2    | '2016-09-23 04:09:22' |    0   |
|  9 | |    1    | '2016-09-23 06:22:59' |    1   |
| 10 | |    3    | '2016-09-23 22:09:22' |    1   |
| 11 | |    1    | '2016-09-24 00:00:22' |    1   |
```

- So in this case I'll get total number of success login from **(20-23 / 09 / 2016)** are: 8  (**day1**= 3 , **day2**= 2 , **day3**= 1 , **day4**= 2)
- **Total number** of success each day within the range from (**'00:00:00'** - **'11:59:59'**) are **5** (**day1**= 2 , **day2**= 1 , **day3**= 1 , **day4**= 1)
- **Average:** 5 / 4 = **1.25**
- **Total number** of success each day within the range from (**'00:00:00'** - **'11:59:59'**) are **3**  (**day1**= 1 , day2= 0 , day3= 1 , day4= 1)
- **Average:** 3 / 4 = **0.75**

I have did the first part to get the total number of success login within datetime range this is my code **(which will return 8)**

```
SET @start_date = '2016-09-20';
SET @start_taime = '00:00:00';

SET @end_date = '2016-09-23';
SET @end_time = '23:59:59';

SELECT SUM(`total_logins`.`number_of_success`) FROM (
    SELECT   COUNT( `login_logs`.`driver_id` ) AS  `number_of_success`
    FROM  `login_logs` 
    WHERE  `login_logs`.`status` = 1
    AND
    `login_logs`.`login_timedate` >= CONCAT(@start_date, ' ', @start_time)
    AND
    `login_logs`.`login_timedate` <= CONCAT(@end_date, ' ', @end_time)
    GROUP BY  `login_logs`.`user_id`
) AS `total_logins`
```

---

**#Update:**
**Expected Output for this code:**

```
| total_logins | 
|       8      |
```

---

I would like to do the next part which calculate the average logins within the same datetime range from XX:XX:XX time to YY:YY:YY time such as this:

> - **Total number** of success each day within the range from (**'00:00:00'** - **'11:59:59'**) are **5** (**day1**= 2 , **day2**= 1
>     , **day3**= 1 , **day4**= 1)
>
>   - **Average:**   5 / 4 = **1.25**

---

**#Update:**
**Expected Output After modifying my code to get avrage from ('00:00:00'** - **'11:59:59') :**

```
|  Avrage_00_12   | 
|       1.25      |
```

---

How should I modify the code to implement this part?

I hope that you understood my question

thank you for your help in advanced

Comment: I don't completely follow your question.  Please show us your expected output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen have update it the question with expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(`number_of_success`) AS `total_success`,
       SUM(`success_range1`) / COUNT(*) AS `average1`,
       SUM(`success_range2`) / COUNT(*) AS `average2`
FROM (
   SELECT DATE(`login_logs`.`login_timedate`), 
          COUNT( `login_logs`.`driver_id` ) AS  `number_of_success`,
          COUNT(CASE 
                   WHEN TIME(`login_logs`.`login_timedate`) 
                        BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '11:59:59' 
                   THEN 1 
                END) AS `success_range1`,
          COUNT(CASE WHEN TIME(`login_logs`.`login_timedate`) 
                          BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '23:59:59' 
                     THEN 1 
                END) AS `success_range2`
   FROM  `login_logs` 
   WHERE  `login_logs`.`status` = 1
          AND
          `login_logs`.`login_timedate` >= '2016-09-20 00:00:00'
          AND
          `login_logs`.`login_timedate` <= '2016-09-23 23:59:59'
   GROUP BY  DATE(`login_logs`.`login_timedate`)) AS t
```

**Output:**

```
total_success, average1, average2
----------------------------------
8,             1.2500,   0.7500
```

Comment: Thank you I think it is working.  how about if I would like to have the maximum and minimum number of logins on the range BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '11:59:59'